# flatness of a kernel

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry

Hi,
let $A$ an abelian scheme over a curve $C$ and $n$ an integer greather than 3 coprime with the characteristic of the ground field. Do you know why the kernel of the multiplication by $n$ is flat over $C$.
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Lemma: if $R\to A\to B$ are local homomorphisms of complete local rings with $A,B$ formally smooth over $R$ of equal relative dimension $g$ and $A\to B$ finite, then $A\to B$ is flat. (Proof by induction on $g$ and taking quotients by regular elements, as in Matsumura, Commutative Ring Theory, p. 179).

Corollary: $[n]:A\to A$, the multiplication by $n$, is flat.

Taking the fiber product of this with the zero-section of $A$ answers your question.